# IBDesignable drawRect not working?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

i am trying to bulid an IBDesignable to put an Icon on the right side of a button label.
It works in the simulator, but storyboard does not reposition the icon to the right.

```
@IBDesignable class IconLabelButtonView : UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init(coder : NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:coder)
        self.setup()
    }

    func setup() {

    }


    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        super.drawRect(rect)

        let imageSize:CGSize = self.imageView.frame.size
        let titleSize:CGSize = self.titleLabel.frame.size

        let labeledIconButtonBufferMagnitude:CGFloat = 6.0

        let imagePadding:CGFloat = ceil(labeledIconButtonBufferMagnitude / 2)
        let titlePadding:CGFloat = floor(labeledIconButtonBufferMagnitude / 2)

        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, (titleSize.width + imagePadding), 0.0, -(titleSize.width + imagePadding))
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, -(imageSize.width + titlePadding), 0.0, (imageSize.width + titlePadding))

    }


}
```

Storyboard View (wrong)

[image: storyboard view]

Simulator View (correct)

[image: simulator view]

Answer (score 1):

You aren’t actually doing any Core Graphics drawing in your `drawRect()` method. Either do some drawing to the current `CGContextRef`, or move that code somewhere like `layoutSubviews()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with one of my custom IBInspectable UIButtons.
Check out my blogpost here: http://www.hixfield.net/blog/2015/03/function-call-order-for-custom-uibutton-with-ibdesignable-ibinspectable/

More particular I think you need to implement the layoutSubviews to correctly position the icon (in my custom button I had to do this to make the label of the button the same as the view of the button)...

Its objective-c code but this still should give you some insight.